# const_cast different behavior: primitive type vs object type

Tags: c++

If we declare a variable as const its content must not change even through a non const reference. In the following code I don't understand why I'm getting a  different behavior depending on the type (primitive vs object):

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass 
{

public:   

   int m_value ;
   MyClass(int value): m_value(value) {} ;


}

int main()
{
 const int x = 0 ;
 const_cast<int &>(x)=20 ;
 std::cout << x << std::endl ; //output 0

 const MyClass a(0) ;
 const_cast<MyClass&>(a).m_value= 20 ;
 std::cout << a.m_value << std::endl ; //output 20 

}
```

Comment: You have a constant object, calling a function which is marked as `const`, and then cast away the constness to modify the object. Why? What is the reason you do something like that? Plain curiosity? Or is there some underlying problem that you want to solve? If there's an underlying problem, then please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: Because your code modifies a const object it has *undefined behaviour*. There are no rules in C++ for how it should behave. If you really want to know why there is a difference then you need to look at your compiler and how it works.

Comment: const MyClass a(0) ; <- your Object is const. But .m_value member is not const, so it is all correct.

Comment: _Except that any class member declared mutable ([dcl.stc]) can be modified, any attempt to modify ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], [expr.pre.incr]) a const object ([basic.type.qualifier]) during its lifetime ([basic.life]) results in undefined behavior:_ http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4.sentence-1.

Comment: So what I'm getting is just a behavior of my compiler and it could be different on a different  compiler

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar Yes exactly, for instance on another compiler your code could crash.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759384/automatic-type-deduction-with-const-cast-is-not-working/53759564#53759564) (or rather, yet another explanation of `const_cast`).

Comment: It seems that the 0 of the first output is not due to the actual value of x (I figured that out by printing another reference to x and the output was 20) but it is just an optimization of the compiler ( replacing x by 0 wherever it appear ). morality never ever try to change a const

Answer (score -2):

You can't cast away the const-ness of the const variable x, since the variable x is a const variable.

<s>what `const_cast` actually do is cast away the const pointer or reference , since your member `m_value` is not a const member , you can modify its value using `const_cast`</s>

[read more on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554841/how-to-use-const-cast)

```
 int x = 0 ;
 const int& p = x; 
 // p = 20; // error: p is const
 const_cast<int &>(p)=20 ;
 std::cout << p << std::endl ; //output 20

-------------------------------------------
```

<s>class MyClass 
    {
    public:

      const int m_value  = 0;
    };</s>

```
int main(){
  const MyClass a;
  const_cast<MyClass&>(a).m_value= 20 ;// undefined behavior
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `m_value` as part of the greater whole is const too. This is just undefined behavior, there is no "explanation" or permit to do it.

Comment: Yeah, just wrong. If an object is const then so are all it's data members (unless they are declared mutable).

Comment: But if an object is declared const doesn't that mean that all its members are const?